# How to draw a diagram showing the structure of an application?

Tags: diagram

What is the most convenient way to draw some small diagram showing the structure of relatively simple GUI application written in C++/C# using WPF and MVVM (MS Visual Studio 2012)?

The diagram should show the basic components of the application and interaction between them (basic interfaces, including C++ and C# method signatures) and probably interaction between multiple threads.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using **Enterprise Architect** [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visio) or **Microsoft Visio** [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_architecture)

Comment: Looks like it is a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of types of diagrams, for the things you need, you could draw UML class diagram (which would describe classes in the application, their interfaces and dependencies) and possibly UML component diagram (which would describe high level components of the application and their interdependencies; one abstraction layer above class diagram).

In terms of tools, you've got bunch of online tools (for example [Gliffy](http://www.gliffy.com/)) and offline tools, as Enterprise Architect or Power Designer.